# codeigniter 3 undefined variable in view

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting error message on view (undefined variable article)

```
<div class="row">
            <? 
            if ($articles){
             foreach ($articles as $article):?>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="category-item wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                        <i class="<?=$article->title?>"</i>
                        <a href="#">"<?=$article->description?>"</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <? endforeach:}?>
            </div>
```

My controller

```
 public function index()
    {
         $data = array();
         $data['articles'] = $this->main_model->get_table_data('masari_sectors',          array(), 5, 'ID','desc');
         
         $this->load->view('site/body', $data);
         
         
    }
```

Please help
Thanks`your text`

Resolve my issues and learn how to fix that

Comment: can you check your get_table_data function on main_model?

Comment: It seems that function(get_table_data) does not return array result

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
        <? 
        if ($articles){
         foreach ($articles as $article)
        { ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
                <div class="category-item wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                    <i class="<?=$article->title?>"</i>
                    <a href="#">"<?=$article->description?>"</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } } ?>
        </div>




public function index()
{
     $data = array();
     $data['articles'] = $articles = $this->main_model->get_table_data('masari_sectors',          array(), 5, 'ID','desc');
     $data['articles'] = $articles;
     $this->load->view('site/body', $data);
     
     
}
```

Comment: While I do think your correction for the view part is correct, I don't think there's anything wrong with the OP's index method. Is there a reason you wrote it that way? Just out of curiosity.